# How do you pass core data corresponding to a row selected in a table?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios6, uitableview

I am learning how to use Core Data. I have an app that fills out all the variable of an entity labeled User. I then take these users and load them to a table. At this point the users can be selected and pushed to a new view controller at which point I generate a PDF file of the user selected. So I think I am misunderstanding what it is I have to pass to the view controller for it to access the core data selected in the table. Here is what I have in my table view controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.spinner startAnimating];
    ReportPDFViewController *reviewViewController = [[ReportPDFViewController alloc] init];
    reviewViewController.userInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:reviewViewController animated:YES];   
}
```

Then the next view states this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email PDF"
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                 target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(emailPDF)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;

    TrafficSignalProAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entitydesc];


    NSError *error;
    NSArray *matchingData = [userInfo executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    NSString *Intersection;
    NSString *currentDay;
    for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData) {
        Intersection = sendIntersection;
        currentDay = sendDate;
    }



    NSString* fileName = [self getPDFFileName];

    [PDFRenderer drawPDF:fileName intersectionSearch:Intersection dateSearch:currentDay];

    [self showPDFFile];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Report";

}
```

So I'm trying to pass the NSManagedObjectContext of the selected row to then load. I am really lost after that. I'm not sure if passing the managed object context is right and if it is I don't know what is wrong with the code in the ReportPDFViewController. I have looked through all the tutorials I can find. I have a limited programming background so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that you would be passing the managed object rather than the context (which would be quite reasonable).  Can you use NSLog at the beginning of `viewDidLoad` to display the value of `userInfo`?

Comment: It gives me the userInfo that I select, which is exactly what I want. Ok so I am doing that correct. Thanks, I guess the only other thing I am confused about is how to access the attributes? [self.userInfo ??].

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much that was all I needed. It works. I have been trying to fix this for far longer then I care to admit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reviewViewController.userInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

This sets userInfo to an object of type NSManagedObject (or a subclass).

```
NSArray *matchingData = [userInfo executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

This is using userInfo as if it's a NSManagedObjectContext. I would imagine you get an invalid selector error here.

What is the actual type of the userInfo attribute? It should be NSManagedObject.

You do not need to do a fetch request in your `viewDidLoad`. Core Data is not a database. You do not always need to do a fetch request every time you want some information. Once you already have a managed object, you can get information related to it without a fetch request. If you've set up a custom class for it, you can treat it almost like it's an regular objective-C object.

```
for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData) {
    Intersection = sendIntersection;
    currentDay = sendDate;
}
```

This code just doesn't make sense. You're looping, but each time through you're assigning the same value to the variables. I don't know what that value is, since `sendIntersection` and `sendDate` are not referred to anywhere else in the code you posted. In any case you're not using the results of the fetch request at all.

I'm going to make a wild guess at what you need to do:

```
Intersection = [userInfo valueForKey:@"intersection"];
currentDay = [userInfo valueForKey:@"date"];
```

It's a total guess, because I don't know what your data model is. No loop is needed, since you only want and have one user object.

Comment: Yes you are correct I had no need to loop. userInfo is a NSManagedObjectContext. It works as it is. All I needed to do was use it to declare my values as you did. I deleted the other code in viewDidLoad that was below the bar button and above the filename code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. The last line of code was all I needed to add to my viewDidLoad. :)

Comment: On another note for anyone else who reads this. It appears I can use NSManagedObject or NSManagedObjectContext. Not quite sure I understand the difference.

Comment: userInfo should be an NSManagedObject, and in fact I think it *is* an NSManagedObject, even if you declare it as NSManagedObjectContext. You can get away with assigning the wrong type because you are assigning it from the result of `objectAtIndex`, which will return an object typed as id. A special loose-typing rule of Objective_C allows you to assign an id type to any type.

Comment: An NSManagedObjectContext is a container in which a bunch of NSManagedObjects live.